# Error when using apt install in Ubuntu shell of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, shell, apt

I was trying to get python and set up an environment to work on the upcoming project.

In Windows 10 Ubuntu bash, I run the following command successfully:

`sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz`

Then I unzipped it and type in some other commands too, until I found that I need gcc in one particular step which I didn't have. So I try the following command:

`sudo apt install gcc`

But then it failed with the following error messages:

```html
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.4
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-96.119
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9
81% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-96.119
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am not familiar with it and it seems to me that it is some kind of connection problem. Why I am encountering this failure and how may I solve it? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Check the firewall.

Comment: Did you do the suggested "maybe run ***apt-get update***"?

Comment: Check the firewall logs see whats been happenin

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the firewall settings that you are using, and possibly in settings IPv4 and IPv6. Reading:

https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/6h71ku/bash_aptget_wont_work/ (last comment)

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/475

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1720